# Creating a label in python and adding it a background color after a button press in a kivy setup

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a label in python with a background color, after I press a button, in a kivy setup.

I have written below code and it is running without error however because of a mistake I cound not find, when I press the button, canvas is not created behind the label. How can I correct it ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class MyWinMan(ScreenManager):
    pass

class W_MainMenu(Screen):

    def button_press(self):

        lbl_info = Label(   
                            text                = 'Please select the file...',
                            size_hint           = ( 1, 0.6),
                            font_size           = 18,
                            color               = ( 180/255, 180/255, 180/255, 1),
                            )

        with lbl_info.canvas:
                Color( 50/255, 50/255, 50/255, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=lbl_info.pos, size=lbl_info.size)

        self.manager.get_screen("win_Main").ids.scr_Main_lvl_A.add_widget(lbl_info)


kv = Builder.load_string("""

MyWinMan:

    W_MainMenu:

<W_MainMenu>:
    
    name:           "win_Main"

    BoxLayout:

        id:             scr_Main_lvl_A
        orientation:    "vertical"
        size:           root.width, root.height
        padding:        40
        spacing:        10

        Button:
        
            text:       'Test'
            id:         btn_chk
            font_size:  20
            on_release: root.button_press()
             
""")

Window.size = (700, 460)
Window.top = 50
Window.left = 100

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rectangle` that you are creating in the `canvas` is using the size of the `Label` at the moment that the `Label` is created. At that moment the size and position of the `Label` are the default size of `(100,100)` and default position of `(0,0)`. The `Rectangle` is not automatically updated when the `Label` size/position is updated. So you must either write code to do the updating, or use `kv` (it will handle the updating for you). So, I suggest creating a custom `Label` class that does what you want. First create a new `Label` class and use it in the `py` code:

```
class LabelInfoButton(Button):
    pass


class W_MainMenu(Screen):

    def button_press(self):
        lbl_info = LabelInfoButton(
            text='Please select the file...',
            size_hint=(1, 0.6),
            font_size=18,
            color=(180 / 255, 180 / 255, 180 / 255, 1),
        )

        # with lbl_info.canvas:
        #     Color(50 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 1)
        #     Rectangle(pos=lbl_info.pos, size=lbl_info.size)

        self.manager.get_screen("win_Main").ids.scr_Main_lvl_A.add_widget(lbl_info)
```

and set the desired behavior in your `kv`:

```
<LabelInfoButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Comment: First of all I want to state that I'm quite new at Python. However thanks to amazing helpfull people such as you are, my progress is faster now. Just a very small correction which is also my own mistake (to not to change the misleading inside text). What I'm trying to create is not a button but a label so  `class LabelInfoButton(Button):` will be `class LabelInfo(Label):` and the rest of the names should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by utilizing Clock.schedule_once as the pos and size values should be obtained after the creation of label but as I guess it was trying to get them before. Therefore I added a bit delay. However a better solution is always welcome...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyWinMan(ScreenManager):
    pass

class W_MainMenu(Screen):

    lbl_info = ""

    def create_my_label(self):

        self.lbl_info = Label(   
                            text                = 'Please select the file...',
                            size_hint           = ( 1, 0.6),
                            font_size           = 18,
                            color               = ( 180/255, 180/255, 180/255, 1),
                            )

        self.manager.get_screen("win_Main").ids.scr_Main_lvl_A.add_widget(self.lbl_info)

    def set_canvas(self, dt=0):

        with self.lbl_info.canvas:
            Color( 50/255, 50/255, 50/255, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=self.lbl_info.pos, size=self.lbl_info.size)

    def button_press(self):

        self.create_my_label()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_canvas)


kv = Builder.load_string("""

MyWinMan:

    W_MainMenu:

<W_MainMenu>:
    
    name:           "win_Main"

    BoxLayout:

        id:             scr_Main_lvl_A
        orientation:    "vertical"
        size:           root.width, root.height
        padding:        40
        spacing:        10

        Button:
        
            text:       'Test'
            id:         btn_chk
            font_size:  20
            on_release: root.button_press()
             
""")

Window.size = (700, 460)
Window.top = 50
Window.left = 100

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: That's an improvement, but the `Rectangle` will not update when your `App` changes size.